# How do I get my bitcoins back if they got sent to an incorrect address?

Tags: address, sending, revert-transaction, malware

I loaded my localbitcoin wallet with a total of $100 - I did 2 separate transactions. The first time I added $50, I tried to send half of it to cardrockcafe but it never showed up, so I tried to add the remaining amount. That also never showed up. A few days later I added another $50 to my localbitcoin wallet and attempted to transfer it to a different website. Again it never showed up. I've set up tickets with all 3 websites and not really getting any responses that are helpful so I've been researching on my own what is going on.

I noticed that when I copied the address and pasted it onto another website the address changed to a completely different one. So I went back to my last few transactions where my money never showed up and the addresses are different as well; meaning the one I was supposed to copy and paste was different when I actually pasted it.

So I added money to a different wallet and I actually typed out the address when I tried to transfer my money to website C instead of copy and pasting them, and the money or bitcoins rather showed up rather quickly. I checked the receiving address of one of the last transactions where my money disappeared and the address is stating the money is still there, but I cannot get to it, or do not know how to retrieve it, can somebody help?

Comment: Can you edit this question down to just the part you are asking about?  I think I know what you are asking, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Ask the person who has the private key corresponding to that address. If that person does not exist, or you don't know who they are, you're screwed.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have caught some malware that replaces Bitcoin your addresses with their own when copy-pasting one. You'll probably want to look into removing the malware from your computer.

Meanwhile, it is unlikely that you'll be able to recover your bitcoins. The Bitcoin network doesn't have a way of reverting payments. Basically, you're in a similar situation as if you handed cash to a different person than the one who was supposed to get it. Unless you can figure out who it was that got it, there is no way to get it back. There is no central registry of Bitcoin users, and as a general rule you cannot identify users from addresses alone.